# xslt 1.0 to convert xs:date to a specific dateFormat DD-MON-YYYY

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new to xslt. so this might be a basic question. I am trying to convert a date received in xs:date format to DD-MON-YYYY
input received is :
`<tns:receivedDate>2017-06-27</tns:receivedDate>`
Output expected
`<tns:receivedDate>27-JUN-2017</tns:receivedDate>`

Thanks in advance

Comment: In XSLT 2.0+ will be simple `format-date(xs:date('2017-06-27'),'[D]-[MN,*-3]-[Y4]')`. You should consider upgrade from an almost twenty years old language version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean convert `YYYY-MM-DD` to `DD-MMM-YYYY`, try:

```
<xsl:template name="format-date">
    <xsl:param name="date"/>
    <!-- day -->
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($date, 9, 2)"/>
    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
    <!-- month -->
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="substring($date, 6, 2)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec', 3*($m - 1)+1, 3)"/>
    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
    <!-- year -->
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($date, 1, 4)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq7k

Comment: Thanks for your reply..The received date is actually in dateTimeFormat.i.e 2002-05-30T09:00:00.My xslt is really big like 1K+ lines..How can i refer this piece of xslt from my larger xslt. Is there a way i can do that?Or how can i add this piece of xslt in my existing xslt

Comment: The code above will work just as well with a dateTime input - see: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq7k/1. --- I don't see your existing XSLT, so I don't know how to integrate this there. See how it works in the demo.

Comment: Thank u so much. I have added my existing xslt in teh answer section below. Sinc i am not able to add it here...with all the lines of code removed just kept one line for example.

Comment: You should add it your question, along with an example of the input. See: [mcve].

Comment: Its not letting me add the complete xslt to the question. I get an error saying too much of code. I.e the reason i had to add it as an answer

Comment: @Simran You asked _"How can i refer this piece of xslt from my larger xslt?"_ Did you mean how to use [`xsl:call-template`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#named-templates) instruction?

Comment: Thanks Michael and @Alejandro. I used template and did a call-template and that worked

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT-1.0 you have to implement the transformation yourself - without the help of build-in functions.

So a solution could look like the following. It uses a data-island in the XSLT to map the month's names. I defined the `tns` namespace to be `http://towelie.namespace`.

The sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:tns="http://towelie.namespace">
    <tns:receivedDate>2017-06-27</tns:receivedDate>
</root>
```

The solution XSLT-1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://towelie.namespace" xmlns:month="http://month.val" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <!-- Data island -->
    <month:val>
        <mon>JAN</mon>
        <mon>FEB</mon>
        <mon>MAR</mon>
        <mon>APR</mon>
        <mon>MAI</mon>
        <mon>JUN</mon>
        <mon>JUL</mon>
        <mon>AUG</mon>
        <mon>SEP</mon>
        <mon>OCT</mon>
        <mon>NOV</mon>
        <mon>DEC</mon>
    </month:val>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tns:receivedDate" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tns:receivedDate">
        <xsl:variable name="year"  select="substring-before(.,'-')" />
        <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'-'),'-')" />
        <xsl:variable name="day"   select="substring-after(substring-after(.,'-'),'-')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($day,'-',document('')/xsl:stylesheet/month:val/mon[number($month)]/text(),'-',$year)" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In this stylesheet the input date is dissected to three variables which are then recombined in the `xsl:value-of` applying an index to the data-island's `mon` elements.

**The output:**

> 27-JUN-2017

**Final comment:**
An important advantage of this approach is that you can define the month's names as you like - with different lengths in different languages - i.e. JAN, Jan, January, Janvier, Januar, Enero, ...

And the data-island could be replaced by external XML files. For example, one for each language.

Comment: _"In XSLT-1.0 you have to implement the transformation yourself. Char(!) by(!) char(!)."_ Your answer does not reflect that.

Comment: @Alejandro: I changed the introduction. Maybe this wording is considered to be more suitable for an XSLT-1.0 answer relating "date"-parts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The input will be in dateTimeFormat.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. My xslt is really big like 1K+ lines..How can i refer this piece of xslt from my larger xslt. Is there a way i can do that?Or how can i add this piece of xslt in my existing xslt

Comment: You can change the matching rule of the template from `match="tns:receivedDate"` to `match="firstElement | secondElement | thirdElement | ..."` to match all the elements you want to change. Apart from that, only the _Data Island_ and the `xmlns:month="http://month.val"` namespace has to be added to your stylesheet.