# Convert date using xml

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have a date in HL7 as "20221201080600" Mountain Time, need to convert that into December 1, 2022 10:06 Eastern Time using xsl.v1.1

Comment: That's two separate questions: how to convert a dateTime between timezones, and how to format the result. For the 1st question, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46196920/3016153. Note that this answer does not take DST into account. For the 2nd question, see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57616405/3016153 and others.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to stackoverflow.com/a/46196920/3016153.  Very helpful.  How can I convert that from 1.0 to 1.1?  Prod system is on v1.1

Comment: There is no need to convert anything. XSLT 1.1 is basically XSLT 1.0 with a few minor changes that do not affect the current issue - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt11/#N14079.